# Xcode HTTP GET Request

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, get, request

I am making an app in which you type a value into a textbox, and the app sends an HTTP GET request to my webserver, ie `www.mywebserver.server.com/ihiuahdiuehfiuseh?' + textbox variable'` However, I have no idea how to work with Xcode. I am experienced in basic PHP and HTML, and advanced C++, but I am so baffled by this Xcode stuff. In all other languages I have worked with, you could look up something like "how to play a sound file in (language)", and you will get something like "oh yeah just do play(mp3url). But, with Xcode, you have to initiate the connection, initiate the variables, etc etc. I bought 2 $30 books, but I am still so confused. So, back to the point, I just need the textbox numerical number to be parsed after the ? in the URl to be parsed as a variable.

Comment: "you could look up something like" i disagree, I hav found numerous classes and examples for xcode/objective-c.  Thats how i learned the language.  So just wanted to say, it is out there.  here is a one good place to start though (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)

Comment: Can you please clarify your specific question? No offence meant, but you've provided a lot of detail in your mini rant, but not much about your actual question. Are you trying to build the URL, build the GET request, actually GET the resource complete with redirection support, or what?

Comment: Xcode it a IDE, it wont perform a GET request for u — never (exept for downloading documentation from developer.apple.com). The framework, you work with, is called Cocoa or Cocoa Touch. If you get the names right, you can stop complaining and start searching.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a non-http get synchronized

You can find more

---

```
-(void)aget:(NSString *)iurl{  
NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:iurl];  
NSURLRequest *res = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  
NSOperationQueue*que=[NSOperationQueue new];  

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:res queue:que completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse*rep,NSData*data,NSError*err){  
    if ([data length]> 0 && err == nil) {  
        NSString* rel=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
        NSLog(@"%@",rel);  
    }else{  
        NSLog(@"isnull");  
    }  

}  
 ];
```

}

---

### Through this launch him

```
NSString * str = [self getDataFrom: @ "your url"];
```

NSLog (@ "% @", str);

---

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UITextFiled`, you would do the following

```
NSString baseUrl = @"www.mywebserver.server.com/ihiuahdiuehfiuseh?"
NSString variable = textField.text;

NSString absoluteURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseUrl, variable];

//Send the absolute variable now to the server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go for a solution like Omar Abdelhafith suggests, don't forget to url-encode your 'querystring'. There is a method in the string class for this: "stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding", but it's not perfect.

I've recently used the solution suggested here: http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/.

Comment: why not just using an NSURL-object?